# Creating maps dynamically for PDF

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, maps, pdf-generation

I'm working on a web app where a user will plug in an address and then it will create a PDF with a map of about 5-10 housing properties within a mile radius. For each property on the map, it will list a few pieces of info like sales price and square-footage.

I have all the data, but I'm wondering what a good way to generate the maps would be, ideally in PHP or Javascript/jQuery. I'm using FPDF/FPDI to generate the PDFs from a template, so the maps have to be in some form where they can be placed on the PDF template. Each time the app is used, the input address will be different, but it will always be in California.

Comment: What's your map source? Sounds like an ideal candidate for using a vector format (to increase quality whilst keeping the file size to a minimum) but most mapping data is available only in bitmap form, afaik.

Comment: Ideally? That sounds an opinion-based question. Nevertheless i suggest that you have to post at least what have you tried. If you use a third part API like Google Map with Open Source app, then you can use PHP. I don't get it why you include java script and jQuery on your options.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Google Maps. However, I think the only way to import images into the PDF from Google Maps is the images coming from the
[Static Maps APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=en-EN&csw=1) though there is some restrictions to their [Terms and Conditions](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en-EN&csw=1).

> License Restrictions. Except as expressly permitted under the Terms, or unless you have received prior written authorization from Google (or, as applicable, from the provider of particular Content), Google's licenses above are subject to your adherence to all of the restrictions below. Except as explicitly permitted in Section 7 or the Maps APIs Documentation, you must not (nor may you permit anyone else to):
>
> (yada yada)
>
> 10.2 copy, translate, modify, create a derivative work of, or publicly display any Content or any part thereof (for example, the following are prohibited: (a) creating server-side modification of map tiles; and (b) stitching multiple static map images together to display a map that is larger than permitted in the Maps APIs Documentation);
>
> 10.8 use the Static Maps API other than in an implementation in a web browser;